# Parsing fasta with specific names in the header

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, biological-neural-network

I have a txt file containing multiple fasta sequences ( and I am willing to parse the sequences together with gene names especially. Can you please help with the selection of sequences with specific names in the header. Thank you

Original data in the txt file.

> lcl|NC_045512.2_gene_6 [gene=ORF6] [locus_tag=GU280_gp06] [db_xref=GeneID:43740572] [location=27202..27387] [gbkey=Gene]
>   ATGTTTCATCTCGTTGACTTTCAGGTTACTATAGCAGAGATATTACTAATTATTATGAGGACTTTTAAAG

Expected data after parsing in python

> ORF6
>   ATGTTTCATCTCGTTGACTTTCAGGTTACTATAGCAGAGATATTACTAATTATTATGAGGACTTTTAAAG

I have used this and I was able to obtain

```
***from Bio import SeqIO
for record in SeqIO.parse("mytext.txt", 'fasta'):
    print(record.name) 
    print(record.seq)***
```

Obtained results were like this.

lcl|NC_045512.2_gene_6 
ATGTTTCATCTCGTTGACTTTCAGGTTACTATAGCAGAGATATTACTAATTATTATGAGGACTTTTAAAG

Comment: check [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
I mean, you can reduce your text content, and the expected output will less too.
finally that users can perceive how your output is different from the expected output

Comment: According to the [SeqIO document: fasta](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO), that says: ``each record starts with a ">" line.`` and I don't see any ">" at your code.

Comment: by the way, if you want to get more help from peoples, you should assume they are newbie, especially the packages(``biopython``) which is not common for programmers that study computer science or math domain.

Answer (score 0):

here i tried it in python regular expression....

here I were grouped the gene and the sequence for two sequences.....

```
import re
f=open('seq',"r")
input=(f.readlines())
print(input)
patt=".+?\[gene=(.+?)]\s\[locus_tag=.+?]\s\[db_xref=GeneID:.+?]\s\ 
[location=.+?]\s\[gbkey=.+?]\s(.+)"
for i in input:
    x=re.search(patt.decode('utf-8'),i.decode('utf- 
    8'),re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE|re.UNICODE)
    print x.groups()
```

the output will be....

```
group1=(u'ORF6',u'ATGTTTCATCTCGTTGACTTTCAGGTTACTATAGCAGAGATATTACTAATTATTATGAGG
 ACTTTTAAAG\n')
 group2=(u'ORF6',u'ATGTTTCATCTCGTTGACTTTCAGGTTACTATAGCAGAGATATTACTAATTATTAT
 GAGGACTTTTAAAG\n')
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/tBk8OK/1 -attached the regex for your clarification..

Answer (score 0):

I still confuse about your question since I did not study biology.

This answer is purely for `souce_text == expected_text`

```
from io import StringIO
from Bio import SeqIO  # pip install biopython  # https://biopython.org/wiki/Download
import re

source_text = """\
>lcl|NC_045512.2_gene_6 [gene=ORF6] [locus_tag=GU280_gp06][db_xref=GeneID:43740572] [location=27202..27387] [gbkey=Gene]
ATGTTTCATCTCGTTGACTTTCAGGTTACTATAGCAGAGATATTACTAATTATTATGAGGACTTTTAAAG
"""

expected_text = """\
ORF6
ATGTTTCATCTCGTTGACTTTCAGGTTACTATAGCAGAGATATTACTAATTATTATGAGGACTTTTAAAG
"""

regex = re.compile("\[gene=[\w]*\] ")  # \w: [a-zA-Z0-9_]
result = ''
for record in SeqIO.parse(StringIO(source_text), 'fasta'):
    # print(record.name)
    gene_name = regex.search(record.description).group()  # [ORF6]
    gene_name = gene_name[gene_name.find('=')+1: -2]  # ORF6
    print(gene_name)
    print(record.seq)
    result += gene_name + '\n' + record.seq + '\n'

if result == expected_text:
    print('ok')
```

```
ORF6
ATGTTTCATCTCGTTGACTTTCAGGTTACTATAGCAGAGATATTACTAATTATTATGAGGACTTTTAAAG
ok
```

## REFERENCE

The following is a reference for people who are not familiar with `biopython`.

- What is [SeqIO.parse](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqIO-module.html)
- What is [fasta](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO)

---

- more [test data](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?db=nuccore&val=973795115&page_size=5&fmt_mask=0&report=gene_fasta&retmode=file)